# Query parameters order in AngularJS URL accessed from Flex

Tags: angular-ui, query-string

I have a web application written in AngularJS (version 1.0.8).
I'm using UI-Router (0.4.) to handle the state of that app.

I try to access the URL of the app from another Flex app (4.0).

In the Angular app, I have the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePage?param01=aaa&param02=bbb
```

In Angular's module.config() of that app, I do something of this sort:

```
$stateProvider.state("somePage", {
    url: "/somePage?param01&param02"
    templateUrl: "view/somePage.html"
    controller: "SomePageController"
});
```

Now in the Flex application, I have the following code:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.param01 = "aaa";
variables.param02 = "bbb";
var url = new URLRequest();
url.data = variables;
navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

The problem is that when I press the button in the Flex app that navigates to the Angular app, I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePage?param02=bbb&param01=aaa
```

In the URL's query parameters, param02 comes before param01.
Then, in Angular's ui-router, I guess, it is changed to the regular URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePage?param01=aaa&param02=bbb
```

My problem with this is with the browser navigation - when the user will click 'back', the browser won't navigate back to the URL of the Flex app, because there's another URL in history, where the query parameters were switched. The user will have to click 'back' twice...

Moreover, though this is an elaboration that's not necessary for the problem, so you can skip it if you'd like, the user can access that Angular app from more than 1 place (i.e. not only from the Flex app). When the user click 'Save' or 'Cancel' in the Angular app, it should be redirected to the originating page. I planned on doing it using the history.back() feature, but it's problematic due to the aforementioned phenomenon, of the URL with the query parameters switched.

Many thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem, currently by changing the way I work with navigateToURL in Flex.

I now have something of this sort:

```
var queryParams:String = "param01=aaa&param02=bbb";
url.url += "?" + queryParams;
navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

This way, when I use a string built by me, instead of the URLVariables class, I can control the order of the URL query params.

Unfortunately, I still don't know why the URL query params are ordered differently every time I use the function, when I do use the URLVariables class...